# font-size inside paragraph and textarea

Tags: html, css

Text inside `#write` is much smaller than inside `.sent`.

I need them both of equal size.

```css
    html{
     font-size:62.5%;
    }
    body{
        font-size:1.4em;
    }
    .sent{
     font-size:1.9rem;
    }
    #write{
     font-size:1.9rem;
    }
```

```html
   <p class="sent">abc</p>
    
    <textarea id="write">abc</textarea>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set same `font-family`. `textarea` has a different font-family than other.

```
.sent{
    font-size:1.9rem;
    font-family: Arial;
}
#write{
    font-size:1.9rem;
    font-family: Arial;
}
```

[**jsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/ke8fh7x3/)

Answer (score 1):

by default textarea has a font-family of `BlinkMacSystemFont` and font-size: `11px`

```css
    html{
     font-size:62.5%;
    }
    body{
        font-size:1.4em;
        
    }
    .sent{
     font-size:1.9rem;
        font-family:san-serif;
    }
    #write{
     font-size:1.9rem;
        font-family:san-serif
    }
```

```html
   <p class="sent">abc</p>
    
    <textarea id="write">abc</textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's your code: https://jsfiddle.net/s92shahm/

If you inspect each element you will discover the following:

```
textarea {
    font-family: monospace;
    border-color: rgb(169, 169, 169);
}
```

While the paragraph has no `font-family` definition, meaning it will default to the main font set by your browser or specified by you.

You need to unify the fonts being used by explicitly setting the `font-family` in use on each. [the following](https://jsfiddle.net/s92shahm/1/):

```
#write,
.sent {
  font-family: 'MyFont', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.9rem;
}
```